# update from select incremental mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to find a solution for this and found several similar posts but none of them answer my question.

I have a badly designed table that stores a sorting index. Programatically we update that index as people sort some data. Problem is that now the indexes look something like `1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, etc` so I'm tasked with fixing this problem. I fixed the code so this doesnt happen anymore but how do I update the db? I have a table:

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| otherId | index | product |
| 3423    | 1     | zbhdfji |
| 63453   | 3     | fgdfgr  |
| 75454   | 3     | drhfef  |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

I need it to be like:

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| otherId | index | product |
| 3423    | 1     | zbhdfji |
| 63453   | 2     | fgdfgr  |
| 75454   | 3     | drhfef  |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

I tried something like:

```
update table set index = @rownum where otherId in (select other_id FROM table where index <= 200 order by index asc );
```

But its not liking that I'm pulling from the same table and i'm not even sure if it would work. Any ideas?

Comment: How does it sort same indexes? Am I correct thinking sort with `otherId` ascending?

Comment: lol i said badly designed table. there is no incrementing id. the "otherId" seems to be unique but it comes from a different table so not incrementing or anything like that. about sorting same indexes... it doesnt... only sorting that ive seen in code is sorting it by index asc and limiting it to 200 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @row_num := 0;
UPDATE `table` SET index = @row_num := @row_num + 1 ORDER BY otherId;
```

Comment: SET @row_num := 0;
UPDATE `table` SET index = @row_num := @row_num + 1 ORDER BY index; worked :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach - instead of updating it, make a new field that is auto-increment and then alter the table and drop the current index field and change the new column to not be auto-increment and rename it back to index? Another option with that new field is run a simple update (update table set index = newfield) and then drop the new field.

Comment: unfortunately that would require too much code change (dont even ask about the code that uses that table... its a nightmare) and would fall out of scope. let me update the "badly designed table" to "badly designed table AND code" lol

Comment: @bia.migueis If you end up with an autoincrement field with same name as the old field, then what code needs to change?

Comment: when something gets added to the table the index of that row is set to 1 and the other rows have their index increased by 1 (yes thousands of update statements every time someone reorders a single product). if i was doing it all over i would have used autoincrement and sort descending so i wouldnt need all these stupid updates but i dont have permission to redo it all :(